# Can I book a Schengen Visa for Germany to a different consulate if the consulates assigned for my state do not have appointments?

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas, consulates

I am non-resident alien (not a permanent resident) residing in Seattle, Washington, USA.

The German consulate assigned for my state is San Fransisco. The earliest available appointment is 2.5 months away.

However, I need to make a business trip to Germany in 2 months. My wife will be accompanying me on a tourist Visa.

I was able to book an appointment in Washington DC 1 month away. However, I do not want to fly from Seattle to Washington DC to be rejected due to this.

Has anyone does this before? What can I do to make sure my appointment is either not cancelled or the application rejected due to this.

I am also open to traveling to another country for a longer duration since my business trip is only for 2 days. Will Germany be considered my main destination since I am applying for a business Visa there, or can I apply to another country as a main destination, if I stay there longer?

Comment: The second question is effectively about the balance between duration of stay and purpose in determining main destination. I think it is important enough to justify a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll post a separate question for the second part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the German Missions in the United States page on [Schengen Visa / Short Stay Visa](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/schengen-visa/963538) an appointment in Washington is not going to work:

> Visas must be applied for at the German Embassy or Consulate General
>   in charge of the applicants place of residence (for example an Indian
>   citizen with H1B Visa residing in Portland/ Oregon must apply at the
>   German Consulate in San Francisco; a Chinese citizen from Bejing
>   visiting the US on a B1/B2 Visa must apply at the German Embassy in
>   Bejing).
>
> Please note that visa applications cannot be processed at a different
>   Consulate or Embassy within the US or in the home country, if the
>   person is residing in the US.